# Facebook + Prompt for publish stream only

Tags: javascript, facebook

If I have a user who is already logged onto facebook but remove my app from his/her account, how can I just prompt for the publish_stream only upon entering my app again since the user has already logged in?

Thanks.

```
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                // request, and the time the access token 
                // and signed request each expire
                uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                accesstoken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                SrReferral = '@ViewBag.Referral';
                window.fbuserid = uid;
                var postData = { facebookUID: uid, facebookAccessTok: accesstoken, facebookSrReferral: SrReferral };
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("DisplayGolfers")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: postData,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function (responseText) {
                        $("#container").html(responseText);
                    }
                });
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                // but has not authenticated your app 
            } else {
                // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
                window.FB.login(function (response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                        accesstoken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                        SrReferral = '@ViewBag.Referral';
                        window.fbuserid = uid;
                        var postData = { facebookUID: uid, facebookAccessTok: accesstoken, facebookSrReferral: SrReferral };
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.Action("DisplayGolfers")',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: postData,
                            dataType: 'html',
                            success: function (responseText) {
                                $("#container").html(responseText);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                        alert('User cancelled login');
                    }
                }, { scope: 'publish_stream' });
            };
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I misinterpreted your question and you want user to stay logged in even if he removed application from his account on Facebook. This is really bad and easily may became security issue.

Once user removed your application he shouldn't be logged-in!

In case you don't want to prompt the user for permissions before he visits your app for the next time you should define what is "next time" in your case (hour/day/browser-session/etc) and set some cookie/session to check every visit if that is the correct time to prompt.

---

You can use second parameter for `FB.getLoginStatus` to always get fresh status of user (which will not return `connected` for user who removed your app).

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  // this will be called when the roundtrip to Facebook has completed
}, true);
```

See *"Roundtrips to Facebook's servers"* section of [`FB.getLoginStatus` documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)

Comment: Thanks Juicy, I was reading the documentation from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/ One of the state is that the user is logged on to FB but yet to authenticate my app which I thought one of the scenario could be that the user logs on, authentic my app but remove it right after from his Account Settings hence there is a 'else if (response.status === 'not_authorized')'. I am not sure why the user shouldn't be logged-in when he removes my app? Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @user415795, well, once user removes your application he's technically still logged-in, but it should be logged out (or provided with a possibility to get back), as soon as you know he isn't the user of your application anymore. Using `FB.getLoginStatus` with a second parameter equal to `true` will ensure fresh status is fetched from Facebook and you'll be aware of the fact that user isn't logged into your app. If you call `FB.getLoginStatus` without second parameter you will get cached `authResponse` which may not represent real status of connection with user...